# Why does function findAllBy crash when I try to get data by the field group

Tags: php

I'm using flavorPHP framework so I have my user table with the field group... I need to get all data with the group = x value, like this:

`$this->findAllBy("group", $x);`

But it crashes... Any idea?

Comment: Crashes, as in...?  Segfault?  Error message?  Exception?  We need a bit more to go on here.

Comment: yeah sorry, it was a SQL error, so it was caused by the reserved word group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at first sight it looks like you're using a mysql reserved word as name for the field, try changing the name or using the back quotes `group` where the query is formed to be executed.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it isn't really a "bug" since it's a problem on the mysql layer, well it's not even a problem to begin with.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: Eh.  I'd consider it a problem with my data access layer, if one has to be careful to avoid common, intuitive names for things because the framework didn't bother to quote them.

Comment: @cHao Using a framework should not restrain you from knowing *some* of mysql reserved words, but yes it's true that it would have been great that it automatically escapes it.